# Transitive closure relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I have a following relation on the set {A,B,C,D} 
R = {(a,a);(a,c);(b,d);(c,d);(d,c)} 
What is the smallest number of tuples that has to be added in order for the relation to become transitive?
It is a bit confusing for me. 
I am sure that I need to add (a,d) since there is a path (a,c) ^ (c,d)  and
I need to add (b,c) since there is a path (b,d) ^ (d,c), but do I need to add (c,c) and (d,d) since there is a path (c,d) ^ (d,c) ?

Comment: Yes, they must be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that we need to add $(a, d), (b, c)$. And yes, for the reason you give, for the relation to be transitive requires that since $(c, d), (d, c) \in R$, we also need to add $(c, c)$ and $(d,d)$.